# Detect when a BrowserView renderer is making network requests and when it is not

Tags: http, sockets, electron

I have an Electron app which renders multiple renderers, each one loads a different website.
I want to monitor every renderer and keep track of the number of HTTP requests it is making at every moment to the website.
It should be between 0-6 based on the number of max sockets that can be opened in parallel per hostname.

How can I do this?